# Posts disappear with Wordpress Multisite using Polylang plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, multisite

I've been searching for the best language/translation plugin for Wordpress on and off for a while and this morning I thought in Polylang I'd found it.  It seems to be sensibly organised and has useful features allowing you to automatically moves pages (and I assumed posts) into the default language for the blog when you activate it.

However my joy was short lived - activating Polylang on a multisite wordpress install also renders all of my blog posts invisible - pages are still there and can be assigned to language specific portions/menus of the site - so structurally it's fine but my blog is gone until I disable the plugin.  There are a few mentions of this happening on other fora but nothing canonical in terms of an explanation.  Any clues?